# Using CSS to hide the last row conditionally

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class = "row">
  <td class = "A"> </td>
  <td class = "A"> </td>
  <td class = "A B"> </td>
</tr>

<tr class = "row">
  <td class = "A B"> </td>
  <td class = "A B"> </td>
  <td class = "A B"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How to hide the last row if all of its children `td` contains class `B`.

I have a calendar that dynamically generate the row and I want to hide the  cell that does not belong to this current month (indicate by class "B"). I want to hide the entire row if all of its children satisfy this condition.

Currently I have

```
  tbody {
    tr:last-child {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

But this will not work as sometimes the last row is partially filled and I dont want to hide it.

Not sure if it is possible with pure CSS selector.

Comment: I would try using jquery as it is way simpler than using css for that.

Comment: CSS alone can't do this. You will need some JavaScript.

Comment: @TimGerhard I am using react with external party library so I am trying to do this with CSS only : )

Comment: @MohammadUsman My requirement is simple enough and CSS manage to handle this case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am using React, I am trying to avoid using Javascript to manipulate dom element. I have discovered a way to do it with CSS

```
tbody {
    tr:last-child {
      td:first-child.B {
        display:none;
      }
      td:first-child.B ~ td  {
          display:none;
      }
    }
  }
```

- First I select the last row `tr:last-child` and
- `td:first-child.B` In this last row the first child that contains `B` class will not be displayed
- `td:first-child.B ~ td` In the same last row, the siblings that has the first child containing B class will not be display too

Answer (score 2):

CSS stands for **Cascading** Style Sheets, so there is no way to style parent node. 
But upcoming CSS4 might come with solution with :has() pseudoclass so your code might just look like this:

```
tr:last-child:has( :first-child.B ){ 
    display : none;
}
```

If the first <td> in last <tr> has class B then entire row will not be displayed. 
That's the future, for now you might use JS or server-sider solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
rows.forEach((row) => {
  let cols = row.querySelectorAll('td');
  let colsB = row.querySelectorAll('td.B');

  if (cols.length == colsB.length) {
    row.style = "display: none;";
  }
})
```

```html
  


    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class = "row row1">
      <td class = "A">a </td>
      <td class = "A">a </td>
      <td class = "A B">b </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class = "row row2">
      <td class = "A B">b </td>
      <td class = "A B">b </td>
      <td class = "A B">b </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

It checks if the total number of `td`'s is equal to total number of `td`'s with the class B then hides the row if so.